# PortAudio callbacks not continuous?

Tags: c++, audio, callback, portaudio

I'm having a problem using PortAudio and I am not sure whether I don't quite understand how the callbacks work, or I did something wrong. My assumption was that the callbacks should fire continuous "on tick", containing the current samples, but it seems like I'm only receiving a few callbacks when I open and start the stream, and then I won't receive callbacks ever again. My code:

```
PaStreamParameters inputP, outputP;
inputP.device = DeviceIndex;
inputP.channelCount = CardInfo->maxInputChannels;
inputP.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
inputP.suggestedLatency = CardInfo->defaultLowInputLatency;
inputP.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

outputP.device = DeviceIndex;
outputP.channelCount = CardInfo->maxOutputChannels;
outputP.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
outputP.suggestedLatency = CardInfo->defaultLowOutputLatency;
outputP.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

PaError err = Pa_OpenStream(
    &AudioStream,
    &inputP,
    &outputP,
    SAMPLE_RATE,
    FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
    paClipOff,
    &CAudio::AudioCallback,
    this
);

err = Pa_StartStream(AudioStream);
```

I used the following constants

```
#define SAMPLE_RATE 44100
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER 64
```

The callback:

```
int CAudio::AudioCallback(const void* pInputBuffer, void* pOutputBuffer, unsigned long iFramesPerBuffer, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void* userData)
{
    CAudio* AudioInterface = (CAudio*)userData;

    const float* buffer = (const float*)pInputBuffer;

    printf("Callback: %d frames per buffer %d t %f\n", AudioInterface->CallbackIndex, iFramesPerBuffer, Pa_GetStreamTime(AudioInterface->AudioStream));
AudioInterface->CallbackIndex++;

    return paContinue;
}
```

Now, what happens if I open and start the stream is that I get exactly six callbacks, the following log output

```
Opening audio stream on 'USB PnP Sound Device: Audio (hw:1,0)'
Opened audio stream, starting it...
Callback: 0 frames per buffer 64 t 21812.485122
Callback: 1 frames per buffer 64 t 21812.497681
Callback: 2 frames per buffer 64 t 21812.514483
Callback: 3 frames per buffer 64 t 21812.525110
Callback: 4 frames per buffer 64 t 21812.626489
Callback: 5 frames per buffer 64 t 21812.635590
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is my understanding of what happens with the callbacks wrong?

Comment: and you know Pa_OpenStream is streaming more data than 6 callbacks worth ?  say if you chop in half FRAMES_PER_BUFFER are you getting twice the number of callbacks ?  if so possibly your stream is getting truncated upstream somehow

Comment: If I set the frames per buffer size to 8, I get exactly 65 callbacks. So maybe you're right, but where and why could that happe

Answer (score 0):

Alright, for now I fixed this by using the blocking API, grabbing the stream and writing it to a buffer in a while loop running in another std::thread, which works kind of good.